# UICollectionViewCell not setting properties correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reloaddata

I am trying to create custom `UICollectionViewCell` which contains few properties, and depending on values of those properties drawing components inside cell. I am using `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` for creating cell, then I am setting some properties, and at the end calling `layoutIfNeeded` function which is overridden inside my custom cell. Overridden function is setting some properties of cell also for example BOOL property is set to YES, and after refreshing cell (calling `reloadData` on collection view) function `layoutIfNeeded` is called again. When I try to read my BOOL property which is set to YES, i am always getting default value which is NO for the first time i call `reloadData`. When I call `reloadData` second time, property is set to YES. Any idea what am I doing wrong? Here is code I am using:

on button click I am calling:

```
[myCollectionView reloadData];
```

method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` looks like:

```
MyCustomCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCustomCell" forIndexPath: indexPath];
cell.device = [collectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
return cell;
```

And code of `layoutIfNeeded` inside `MyCustomCollectionCell.m`

```
-(void)layoutIfNeeded{
    NSLog(@"bool prop: %d",changedStatus);
    changedStatus = YES;

}
```

BOOL property is defined in `MyCustomCollectionCell.h` :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL changedStatus;
```

UPDATE:

I am sorry, I made a mistake in my post. I am not refreshing collection with `reloadData`, but with `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`; This call causes init method of my custom cell to be called again (not just when collection view is loaded for the first time) and after that `layoutIfNeeded`. I thing problem is that cell is not reused, but created again, causing all properties to disappear. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you specify when (in relation to calling `-reloadData`) are you reading `changedStatus` ?

Comment: `reloadData` is called inside `viewController` class and `changedStatus` is set and printed inside `MyCustomCollectionCell`. First is called `reloadData`, then method `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, inside that method `layoutIfNeeded`, and inside `layoutIfNeeded` is printed `changedStatus` and then set new value.

Comment: bro i just created a blank project and copied your code and pasted in my proj. just added one line after @implementation. synthesize changedStatus. and worked fine. don't know why but worked.

Comment: I have created blank project too and this code worked for me. Something else is wrong within my logic which is complex, and it is simplified only to post this question. Thanks Mahesh.

Comment: I found code which is creating error in my project. I am not calling `reloadData`, but `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` with specific index. After that call, first time `init` method of cell is called, every other time just `layoutIfNeeded` is called only.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use cells to store state data. Cells get used, put in the reuse queue, and then recycled. The specific cell object that stores the data for a particular indexPath may change when the table is reloaded, when a cell is reloaded, when you scroll to expose new cells, etc.

Save state data in your data model.

Comment: Why am I then getting correct values after second press of button? Each time I am getting correct value, except first time. It is not relevant if cell is visible or not. It is always set correctly after second press.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of `changedStatus` property ?

Try setting `changedStatus = YES;` in `layoutSubviews` instead :

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.changedStatus = YES;
}
```

Comment: I have more complex system which contains 5 NSString properties and 3 BOOL properties, which I am reading later on. Depending on values of those 8 properties, different content is updated and presented when user press button. Why do I need to read it with self attribute if @synthesize is applied?

Comment: @DuncanC answer is the best, you should work with your model outside your cells, which are intended to display model only. The `self.` accessor is just my coding style :)

Answer (score 0):

Set this changedStatus Bool inside your ViewController instead of UICollectionViewCell.

BOOL property is defined in YourViewController.h :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL changedStatus;
```

When you you want to refresh the CollectionView

```
[myCollectionView reloadData];
changedStatus = YES;
```

Then inside your `MyCustomCollectionCell.m` create a new method like,

```
-(void)customLayoutIfNeeded : (BOOL)status{
    NSLog(@"bool prop: %d",changedStatus);
    changedStatus = YES;

}
```

Add this to `MyCustomCollectionCell.h` as well.

Then inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` do this,

```
MyCustomCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCustomCell" forIndexPath: indexPath];
cell.device = [collectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell customLayoutIfNeeded: changedStatus];
return cell;
```